# stuck in loop do while loop while using try

Tags: java

I am string to make a simple Calculator if some one divides by  zero it does not break the code. I honestly have  no ideal what to I did every thing that i could.I need to get this don't for school.my home work reads perform addition, subtraction,multiplication and division on two numbers.handle invalid Exception and arithmetic Exception.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Calcultator {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int w1=0;
    int w2=0;
    int w3=0;
    double i1 = 0;
    double i2=0;
    String sign1 = null;
    double sum=0;
    do {
        try {   
            System.out.println("Enter a your first number");
            i1=scan.nextDouble();
            w1++;
            System.out.println("il="+1l);
            System.out.println("w1="+w1);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("you must enter a number");  
            w1=0;
        }
    } while(w1==0);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a your first number");                
            i2=scan.nextDouble();
            w1++;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("you must enter a number");  
        }
    } while(w2==0);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("1)/ 2)* 3)- 4)+");
            int sign=scan.nextInt();
            switch(sign) {
                case 1:
                    if(i1==0 || i2==0){
                        System.out.println("Zero can not be Devided");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        sign1="/";
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    sign1="*";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sign1="-";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sign1="+";
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("you must enter a number");  
        }
    } while(w3==0);

    if(sign1=="/") {
        sum=i1/i2;
        System.out.println(i1 +"/"+i2+"="+sum);
    } else if(sign1=="*") {
        sum=i1*i2;
        System.out.println(i1 +"*"+i2+"="+sum);
    } else if(sign1=="-") {
        sum=i1-i2;
        System.out.println(i1 +"-"+i2+"="+sum);
    } else {
        sum=i1+i2;
        System.out.println(i1 +"+"+i2+"="+sum);
    }

    scan.close();
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623651/scanner-nextline-return-null/28623706#28623706

Comment: Please format you code correctly with consistent indentation.  It is currently very hard to read. I suspect you use a combination of spaces and tabs, which is why it gets mangled.  For SO it works best if you use only spaces to indent so there's no ambiguity about how wide a "tab" is.

Comment: Hint: your catch statement is **not** helpful. It just tells you that "same error occurred". Change it to tell **what** kind of error happened, for example by printing its message and/or stacktrace. And code formatting **matters**. I would also suggest to spent more time on **naming**,  as the names you are using tell **nothing** about the things behind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you've done a bad copy/paste in the second do-while loop:

```
do {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter a your first number"); // should say "Enter a your second number"         
        i2=scan.nextDouble(); // correct
        w1++; // should be w2 - but I'd use a bool instead
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("you must enter a number");
        //need to set w2 in here - added below
        w2 = 0;
    }
} while(w2==0);
```

`w2` is never changed in this loop (you changed `w1` instead), so it will always be 0 and you'll never exit the loop.
Instead of using `int w1,`, `w2`, and `w3`, then not reusing them, I'd use a single (meaningfully named) boolean variable as a matter of style:

```
boolean validInput = false;
do {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter your first number");
        i1 = scan.nextDouble();
        validInput = true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You must enter a number");
        validInput = false;
    }
} while(!validInput);
validInput = false;
// Second loop to follow using validInput instead of w2
```

Your switch statement looks mostly good, but again, you never change `w3`. I'd suggest using `validInput` again. In your first case, you also state that zero cannot be divided, which is incorrect. 0 can be divided (0/anything == 0), but you cannot divide by zero. You also need to handle the case where the user enters an invalid operation (i.e sign < 1 or sign > 4). 
I'd also do the calculation where you set the signs, eliminating the need for multiple calculations at the end. 
What I'd suggest:

```
validInput = false;
double result  = 0;
String operationStr = null; // I'll use operationStr instead of sign1, so the reader knows what it's for
do {
    try {
        // More understandable output for the user (unless it must be in the format you supplied)
        System.out.println("Enter an operation: ");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for /");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for *");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for -");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 for +");
        int inputOperation = scan.nextInt(); // inputOperation instead of sign for readability: + and - are signs, * and / aren't.
        switch(inputOperation) {
            case 1:
                if(i2 == 0){ // only need to worry about dividing BY zero
                    System.out.println("Error: cannot divide by zero - undefined");
                } else {
                    operationStr = "/";
                    validInput = true;
                    result = i1 / i2;
                }
                break; // only really need one break statement, but this is again a trivial matter of style.
            case 2:
                operationStr = "*";
                validInput = true;
                result = i1 * i2;
                break;
            case 3:
                operationStr = "-";
                validInput = true;
                result = i1 - i2;
                break;
            case 4:
                operationStr = "+";
                result = i1 + i2;
                break;
            default:
                // An invalid int was entered, out of the range of our operators
                System.out.println("Error: Please enter a valid operation: 1, 2, 3, or 4 ")
                break;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("you must enter a number");
    }
} while(validInput  = false);

System.out.println(i1 + operationStr + i2 + "=" + result);
scan.close();
// End of program
```

As a final note, there are many spelling errors and badly named variables in your code that you may want to fix up, the marker won't be too impressed with sloppy grammar or bad spelling. Try to name your variables based on what they **do**, so that your marker and anyone reading it can easily understand your code. For example, name i1 input1 instead. Use `boolean validInput` instead of `int w1, w2, w3`, as these have no meaning by looking at them. Use spaces between values in operations involving variables for readability, and finally, use **indentation** properly so the reader can make sense of your loops.

Comment: thank very much. so why was it stuck in the first loop and the catch statement not work. I was not to focused on the second other loops if I couldn't get the the first loop to work.Oh sorry for the sloopy  code.I am still new new at it.I understand the basics. It does not help in school I have been learning android programing to using can get little confusing at times. Them both using java and being so different.Thank ypu I will do my best to take your advise.Thank you again.